# How to add smart contracts support in parachain?

Tags: polkadot, cumulus

I am using Cumulus SDK for my parachain.  Works well, but I need to be able to upload smart contracts into my parachain.  How can I do this, Cumulus polkadot-parachain does not have smart contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Substrate tutorials you can find the [guide](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/) on adding the `pallet-contracts` to the runtime. Then you can use polkadot-js-apps to upload contract code.

Comment: This can be done easily in the Node template.  I would like to replicate this using Cumulus SDK.  I am having a hard time finding the runtime to modify.

Comment: The basic runtime you would modify would be this one, I believe https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs However, you have more runtimes available in the `runtimes` folder, and this one appears to already have the contracts pallet, like you need https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo - you can select a different runtime to use with the `--chain` flag.

Comment: aaahhh....thanks....thats what I need.

Comment: do you happen to have documentation how to run a parachain using the parachain-template and a local polkadot relay chain?

Comment: Sure - you would start with this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/

Comment: Do you have a sample parachain-template that has a pallet-contracts configured.  I am loss in adding the pallet.

Comment: for instance here https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/master/runtime/src/lib.rs

Comment: Thanks so much...this should be a great help.